# ubuntu server suddenly switched to a gui

Tags: server, 20.04, raspberrypi

I installed and was using ubuntu server 20.04 on my raspberry pi 4. I was using it when admittedly I did click a bunch of random keys trying to remember the command for something. I looked away for a few minutes and when I came back there was a gui. I wasn't sure what I did and ctrl alt f1 just  gets stuck forever. Rebooting comes back to the gui. I need to put it back in server mode.

Comment: Ubuntu server is headless, no GUI. If you're seeing one is because you installed one (and then somehow managed to login in a graphical session but not sure how?).

Comment: I ended up fixing this by running a command that boots into server version by default. I must have installed it as one of the dependencies for this package I installed before( 5gb of dependencies ).

Comment: @SaveerJain if you could list the command you ran, it would be immensely useful for us who have the same problem. Thanks !